# Definition of smooth manifolds in Milnor's characteristic classes

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, characteristic-classes

I just started reading Milnor's characteristic classes, but I got a bit annoyed with his definition of manifolds, smooth maps, tangent spaces etc. since he embeds everything into Euclidean spaces. Is there any crucial inconvenience that I will encounter in this book if I just use "usual" definition of those concepts (ones essentially formulated in the language of locally ringed spaces)? Also, I am not perfectly sure that an embedding into an Euclidean space uniquely determines a differential structure on a topological manifold, i.e., I am concerned that his definition only says existence of differential structures but does not fix one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any abstract $n$ manifold admits an (smooth) embedding in an Euclidean space $\mathbb R^N$ for $N$ large enough (depending on $n$), see Whitney's embedding theorem.
Therefore there is no lack of generality in adopting Milnor's definition.
The smooth structure of submanifold is determined as it is inherited by the ambient space.

I can imagine that the authors adopted that definition because it is much easier and intuitive to give and suffices to their aims.
Another author famous for preferring the definition of manifold  given  terms of submanifolds of $\mathbb R^N$ was Vladimir Arnold.

Comment: You should verify yourself that there is a unique differential structure on the submanifold such that the inclusion map is smooth.

Comment: I’m also curious about your reference to the definition of a manifold as a locally ringed space. By this, do you mean the standard one using an atlas of coordinate charts?

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain Thank you for the comment. I realize that the second question is trivial. I knew Whitney’s embedding theorem, but to me (and I guess from a modern perspective) it is awkward to  give unnecessary information of an embedding, so I am wondering if I can just ignore his definitions and keep reading.

Comment: @Deane It is equivalent to the one using an atlas. For example it is discussed in Wedhorn’s Manifolds, Sheaves, and Cohomology (in particular the equivalence is stated in p. 79)

Comment: @P.Usada If I recall correctly that book, if you wouldn't have read the first chapter you probably wouldn't have noticed that they are using that definition.

Comment: Going off topic again. I’ve rarely seen the locally ringed space definition used in practice. Anyone know examples where it is?